# keycloak - User login by phone and OTP (not by username / password)

Tags: spring-security, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am looking to completely remove the username-password step in my auth execution flow. I want user to login using phone number and OTP. Please assume, users are already set up with valid phone numbers in keycloak.
Can you please guide me any reference/pointer which suggests user to directly input his/her phone for validation (not the user/password.)

Thanks

Comment: you need to write custom authenticators. Briefly: 1. authenticator which finds the user from phone number and then 2. send OTP as challenge.   you can reference from https://github.com/altanovela/keycloak-auth-otp-sms

Comment: Hi @MuhammedYalçınKuru . thanks for the guidance. I am having hard time understanding this in "english" language. how can i translate the content on this page to English please

Comment: sorry for that. you can also check this https://www.n-k.de/2020/12/keycloak-2fa-sms-authentication.html they used username and password with otp. instead of username and password authenticator, write your own authenticator which found user by phone number.

Comment: and also you can check keycloak doc to write your custom authenticator https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_auth_spi

Comment: Thanks @MuhammedYalçınKuru ..one question. in your first url. https://github.com/altanovela/keycloak-auth-otp-sms  there is a requestotpcontroller.. so that means the code has to be running on localhost:8085 as you indicated in the constants.. i don't see an entry point main () in the code so how can i run it? registerotp will call localhost:8085 to validate an OTP so will the deployment in jar take care of running the controller also on the localhost? thanks

Comment: Also @MuhammedYalçınKuru .. do i need to create a new realm "akuid" as per your code.
if so then i think the auth flow for login and registration need to be set up in akuid relam.. then what would be the url to access keycloak for the newly created relam?

Comment: I think you don't need  the requestotpcontroller. As you see, OtpSmsFormAuthenticator already sends otp sms and validates it.  And also you don't need to create new realm if you aren't using master.

Comment: he create requestotpcontroller to get and validate for registration form. instead of that you can write  somewhere else  like table to compare input and send otp.

Comment: Hi @MuhammedYalçınKuru - I tried  github.com/altanovela/keycloak-auth-otp-sms but  after my registration and browser flow i am being redirected to keycloak 403 forbidden page. I didn't create a new realm.. i have set up the phone/otp browser flow in master realm only. Can you pls suggest me why i am being routed to to keycloak forbidden page thanks.